# Item da lista exercer a mesma função de um ícone

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, front-end

Estou fazendo um menu lateral com sub-menus. Esses sub-menus são ativados por um ícone pelo javascript. Porém, queria adicionar a mesma função do ícone, ao `<li>` para ficar mais funcional e intuitivo.

[menu lateral fechado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcbag.png)  |  [menu lateral aberto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Si9p.png)

```
         <div class="iocn-link">
           <a href="#">
             <i class='bx bx-message-square-edit'></i>
             <span class="link_name">Cadastro</span>
           </a>
           <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
         </div>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Cadastro</a></li>
           <li><a href="../CadastroUsuario/index.php" >Cliente/Fornecedor </a></i></li>
           <li><a href="../Produto/produto.php" >Produto</a></li>
           <li><a href="../Unidade de Medida/uniMed.php">Unidade de Medida</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
         <div class="iocn-link">
           <a href="#">
             <i class='bx bx-book-alt' ></i>
             <span class="link_name">Consulta</span>
           </a>
           <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
         </div>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Consulta</a></li>
           <li><a href="../Cadastro.Usuario/indexC.php" >Cliente/Fornecedor </a></i></li>
           <li><a href="../Produto Consulta/produtoC.php" >Produto</a></li>
           <li><a href="../Unidade de Medida Consulta/uniMedC.php">Unidade de Medida</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li>

       <li>  
             <div class="iocn-link">
               <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-file-find'></i>
                 <span class="link_name">Serviços</span>
               </a>
               <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
             </div>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
               <li><a class="link_name arrow" href="#">Serviços</a></li>
               <li><a href="../consultacnpj/consultacnpj.php">Consulta CNPJ</a></i></li>
               <li><a href="../importarxml/index.php" >Importar XML</a></li>
               <li><a href="../consultacliente/consultacliente.php" >Consulta de Cliente</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
```

Java Script:

```
<script>
  //Java Script do Menu Lateral

  let arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
            for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
              arrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
           let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;//selecting main parent of arrow
            arrowParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
            });
          }
          let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
          let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-menu");
          console.log(sidebarBtn);
          sidebarBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
            
          });
</script>
```

Comment: Você pode deixar alguns prints para mostrar a barra e os itens expandidos?

Comment: @CésarRodriguez vou anexar

Answer (score -3):

Olá.

Já que classe "arrow" está associada ao elemento "a" dentro das suas "li", você pode associar a função que será executada quando a "li" for clicada, utilizando a propriedade parentNode de cada elemento "a.arrow".

function clicar(){
window.alert(this.innerText)
}

document.querySelectorAll('.arrow').forEach(a=>{
a.parentNode.addEventListener('click',clicar)
})

Veja se consegue acessar o exemplo [aqui](https://codepen.io/henrique-moraes/pen/ExRbjZb)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

É só você mudar o alvo dos eventListeners dos cliques para os LIs (e depois ajustar a referência para os elementos que terão a classe showMenu adicionada). Na verdade, no seu caso os alvos seriam as divs filhas dos LIs.

Tenta o seguinte. Se não der certo, é alguma alteração boba no `const parent etc`.

Detalhe: seu código tem uma classe soletrada `iocn-link`. Deve ser "icon" soletrado errado, mas vou manter desse jeito abaixo.

```js
const iocnLinkDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".iocn-link");
iocnLinkDivs.forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const parentLi = e.target.parentElement; //selecting main parent of div
    parentLi.classList.toggle("showMenu");
  });
});
// O restante segue inalterado
```